# Can't Assign a Database Object to Another, Validation failed: Class must exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

I am seeding a database using two `CSV` files to create two tables, `continents` and `emissions`. `continents` uses a file of countries with demographic data on each country, `emissions` uses a file of CO2 emissions with multiple entries for each country from every year since 1850. `Emission` is supposed to belong to `Continent` based on which country each record represents.The first table relates to `Continent` class by `has_many` and has a scaffold built for `MVC`, and the second table just has a model and `belongs_to` the `Continents` class.

I am trying to seed the tables using a rake file, first seeding the `continents` table and then seeding the `emissions` table, where the `emissions` table has an attribute called `continent_id` so that it belongs to a `Continent` object. I am trying to do this by searching for the correct Continent id using

```
Continent.select(:id).where("Country = ?", country_temp)
```

However I am getting an error that states `Validation Failed: Continent must exist`

**continents.rake**

```
require 'csv'
namespace :continents do
  desc "pull worlddata into database"
  task seed_continents: :environment do

    #drop the old table data before importing the new stuff
    Continent.destroy_all
    Emission.destroy_all

    CSV.foreach("lib/assets/Socio-Economic_Baseline_Data.csv", :headers =>false) do |row |
      puts row.inspect #just so that we know the file's being read

      #create new model instances with the data
      Continent.create!(
      Continent: row[0],
      Country: row[1].to_s,
      Population: row[2].to_i,
      Population_density: row[3].to_i,
      Urban_population: row[5].to_i,
      Urban_population_coastal: row[6].to_i,
      GDP_per_capita: row[7].to_i,
      Land_area: row[12].to_i,
      Cropland_area: row[13].to_i,
      Pasture_area: row[14].to_i,
      Water_per_capita: row[17].to_i,
      Commercial_energy_consumption: row[31].to_i,
      Traditional_fuel_consumption: row[32].to_i,
      Commercial_hydroelectric_consumption: row[33].to_i
    )
    end

    CSV.foreach("lib/assets/CAIT Country CO2 Emissions.csv", :headers =>false) do |row |
      puts row.inspect #just so that we know the file's being read

      country_temp = row[0].to_s
      continent = Continent.select(:id).where(Country: country_temp)
      puts continent

      #create new model instances with the data
      Emission.create!(
      continent_id: continent,
      year: row[1].to_i,
      pollution: row[2].to_f,
    )
    end
  end
end
```

**continent.rb**

```
class Continent < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :emissions
    validates :Continent, :Country, :Population, :Population_density, :Urban_population, :Urban_population_coastal, :GDP_per_capita, :Land_area, :Cropland_area, :Pasture_area, :Water_per_capita, :Commercial_energy_consumption, :Traditional_fuel_consumption, :Commercial_hydroelectric_consumption, presence: true
end
```

**emission.rb**

```
class Emission < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :continent
end
```

**schema.rb**

```
# This file is auto-generated from the current state of the database. Instead
# of editing this file, please use the migrations feature of Active Record to
# incrementally modify your database, and then regenerate this schema definition.
#
# Note that this schema.rb definition is the authoritative source for your
# database schema. If you need to create the application database on another
# system, you should be using db:schema:load, not running all the migrations
# from scratch. The latter is a flawed and unsustainable approach (the more migrations
# you'll amass, the slower it'll run and the greater likelihood for issues).
#
# It's strongly recommended that you check this file into your version control system.

ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2019_10_18_200535) do

  create_table "continents", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "Continent"
    t.string "Country"
    t.integer "Population"
    t.integer "Population_density"
    t.integer "Urban_population"
    t.integer "Urban_population_coastal"
    t.integer "GDP_per_capita"
    t.integer "Land_area"
    t.integer "Cropland_area"
    t.integer "Pasture_area"
    t.integer "Water_per_capita"
    t.integer "Commercial_energy_consumption"
    t.integer "Traditional_fuel_consumption"
    t.integer "Commercial_hydroelectric_consumption"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "emissions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "continent_id"
    t.integer "year"
    t.float "pollution"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["continent_id"], name: "index_emissions_on_continent_id"
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving my problem so I figured I'd post the solution

I switched this line

```
continent = Continent.select(:id).where(Country: country_temp)
```

with this code

```
continent = Continent.where(["Country = ?", country_temp])
continent = continent[0]
puts continent
```

I believe the problem was that I was using the 'where' method to get an array of 'continents' to match this criteria and I just wasn't setting my variable to the first entry in the array so I could use the 'id' method. 'continent_id' wasn't looking for an array and I was passing it one.

```
CSV.foreach("lib/assets/CAIT Country CO2 Emissions.csv", :headers =>false) do |row|
      puts row.inspect #just so that we know the file's being read

      country_temp = row[0].to_s
      continent = Continent.where(["Country = ?", country_temp])
      continent = continent[0]
      puts continent

      #create new model instances with the data
      Emission.create!(
      continent_id: continent.id,
      year: row[1].to_i,
      pollution: row[2].to_f,
      )
    end
```

After this I was able to reference 'emissions' in the 'continent' controller so I could use the 'emissions' data with my 'continent' objects.

Hope this helps if anyone encounters a similar problem.